# InsertModelSDF potential race condition

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to programmatically add objects to an environment with `InsertModelSDF`. There seems to be a race condition that causes this to sporadically fail if `InsertModelSDF` is called too quickly after `init_world`. [This test script](https://github.com/mkoval/gazebo_tests/blob/master/AddObjectRaceDemo.cpp) reliably fails on the first iteration and, additionally, sometimes fails on the second iteration of the loop:

Additionally, I noticed a few other quirks that are potentially relevant:

1. `GetModel` only returns the new model after `runWorld` has run for at least one timestep.
2. There is no reliable way of telling if `InsertModelSDF` failed.

Am I doing something wrong in my test script (e.g. neglecting acquire a lock)? Also, is there any way to force this data to refresh without running a simulation timestep?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7711/insertmodelsdf-potential-race-condition/) by [mkoval](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/621/mkoval/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-12-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NickDP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/964/nickdp/) on 2014-12-16**:
In your test script you don't declare `model_path`. Can you fix it?

**Comment by [mkoval](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/621/mkoval/) on 2014-12-17**:
I accidentally removed that line when cleaning up the code. It's fixed now (same URL).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Regarding your additional questions, my question and nkoenig's answer [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7665/insert-model-programmatically-and-get-its-model/?answer=7671#post-id-7671) is relevant.

---

Originally posted by [NickDP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/964/nickdp/) with karma: 186 on 2014-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mkoval](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/621/mkoval/) on 2014-12-16**:
This is likely the source of the issue. However, I am not sure why. I am manually triggering simulation timesteps with the `gazebo::runWorld` function. Shouldn't this force processing of the queue?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This happens because we don't process messages every iteration of simulation. Our strategy is to let messages that don't need immediate processing to linger a bit. The effect is a small delay in things like inserting new models, with more time given to the physics engine.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-12-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mkoval](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/621/mkoval/) on 2014-12-17**:
Thanks! What is the recommended way of waiting for the model to be inserted? @NickDP's post uses a spinlock to wait until `GetModelCount()` increases. I am attempting to use Gazebo programmatically (in-process), so it is undesirable to trigger several physics updates every time I add a model. Ideally, I'd like to run the message processing manually (without also triggering a simulation step).

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-12-17**:
You should be able to listen to the `~/model/info` topic. Or you can connect to the [addEntity](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/826e8cdd630d0292a439aafe92f8a160f17e4d4d/gazebo/common/Events.hh?at=default#cl-124) event.

**Comment by [mkoval](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/621/mkoval/) on 2014-12-17**:
Thanks. The `AddEntry` event looks like what I want. Is there any way to process the message queue without also triggering a simulation step?